# enable webGL automatically?

Tags: javascript, browser, webgl

I am using [glfx.js](http://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/demo/) jquery plugin for adjusting image's hue/saturation but most of the browser not supporting WebGL

is there a way to automatically enable webgl in browser if website uses it?

I know that you need to enable it manually in Safari, and there is a plugin for IE.

Or Is there any way so we can know at the time of page load that WebGl is disabled ?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to automatically enable WebGL in a browser. It's in the hands of the browser vendor to enable it by default - Safari and IE are the two latecomers in that area. WebGL is coming in IE11 ([source](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/13/04/02/2127205/ie11-to-support-webgl)), and I would imagine the next release of Safari will have it on by default (it's been over a year since the last release).

You can however detect if WebGL is enabled.

As you're probably aware, glfx.js spits out an error message if WebGL isn't enabled. It sounds like you're trying to take some other action if that's the case (no WebGL support).

Looking at the glfx.js documentation, they provide this example:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // try to create a WebGL canvas (will fail if WebGL isn't supported)
    try {
        var canvas = fx.canvas();
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
        // Here is where you want to take some other action
        // For example, redirecting to another page with window.location.href = ...
        return;
    }
}
```

For those reading this not using glfx.js, theeasiest check is to use `!!window.WebGLRenderingContext`, but that doesn't always work (some browsers throw back false positives). Your best be is to create a canvas element and check for the WebGL context:

```
function webGLSupport()
{
    var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    var webgl = false;

    try
    {
        webgl = !!( canvas.getContext( 'webgl' ) || canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl' ) );
    }
    catch(e) {};

    return webgl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but as you know I am using glfx.js for brightness/contrast so it is not supported by most of the browsers even I am using Mozila 21.0 but it's not supporting webgl and same problem with Google chrome , chrome is supporting webgl but when I change value of brightness/contrast then image is completely black. Do you know any other jquery plugin for brightness/contrast. Thanks!